# Server responds with 403 but works upon website refresh

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, nginx, http-status-code-403

**Technologies:** I have a VPS server (ubuntu) on which I host an app. The client is written with Vue, the server with express, and I use NGINX as webserver and PM2 to run my express server.

**The problem:** I am able to successfully fetch from my server, but after a few hours of the client being open on the web browser, I suddenly receive 403 for each request. A page refresh always solves that.
I DO NOT USE TOKENS OR AUTH AT ALL, so that's not the reason.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide more details about your question

Comment: @OlegPro Because the problem might involve different things, like nginx configs, pm2, my express server, etc, I'm not sure what bit of code to provide, if that's what you mean